# I am unable to download the excel sheet in staging environment

Tags: php, elgg

```
$users=elgg_get_entites( type= "users",
                           limit = "9999" );
echo "<Table>";
$columns= "<TR><TH>ID</TH><TH>Name</TH><TH>Username</TH>Email<TH></TR>"
echo $columns.'/t';
foreach($users as $user){
$guid=$user->guid;
$name=$user->name;
$username=$user->username;
$email=$user->email;
$banned= $user->banned;
if(banned == 'no'){ $body = "<tbody><tr><td>".$guid."</td><td>".name."</td><td>".username."</td><td>.email.</td></tr></tbody>"
}
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream"); header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Reoprt.xls"); header("Pragma: no-cache"); header("Expires: 0");
echo $data.'/n';  } echo "</table>";
```

in my above code, it's work's fine in local. I am able to download the excel sheet format with data in local. But same code placed in staging, i am unable to download the excel sheet format with data. it displays only data on white screen. Please suggested me how to solve the issue.Advance thank you. Please help me.

Comment: Maybe an improper mime type setup in your staging server settings as the one described here : http://serverfault.com/questions/19060/why-are-docx-xlsx-pptx-downloading-from-webserver-as-zip-files

Comment: Thank you Kenavoz, for giving important information to me.